# Struct problems

Tags: c, struct, scanf

```
typedef struct{
    char noreg[11];
    float IPK;
}Mahasiswa; 

void showDataArr(Mahasiswa *A, int ukuran){
    int i;  
    for(i=0;i<ukuran;i++){  
        printf("Mhs ke %d\n",i+1);
        printf("\tNoreg : %s\n",A[i].noreg);
        printf("\tIPK   : %.2f\n",A[i].IPK);
    }
}

void isiDataArr(Mahasiswa *A, int ukuran ){
    int i;
    char temp[20];
    for(i=0;i<ukuran;i++){  
        printf("Masukan Noreg : ");
        scanf ("%[^\n]",A[i].noreg);
        printf("Masukan IPK   : ");scanf("%f",&A[i].IPK);
        getchar();
    }
}

int n;
main(){

    Mahasiswa PTIK[n];

    printf("masukan jumlah data :");
    scanf("%d",&n); //this part
    isiDataArr(PTIK,n);
    printf("\n");
    showDataArr(PTIK,n);
    getch();
}
```

Hello i have that code right over there, my problem is when i run it the scanf would make the program bypass the first array input the "masukan no reg" would be left blank
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD0BC.png)
the rest array however would run normally

Comment: Seriously, posting a link to an image was easier than pasting text as text? **Post text as text, not images!**

Comment: If n is 0... ?! What do you think the first line of code would do?

Comment: `Mahasiswa PTIK[n]`. That's clearly wrong as `n` is 0 at that declaration point. So your array is 0 sized.

Comment: Also, it is supposed to be `int main(void)`. Your compiler should have complained about this.

Comment: And you should get a bunch of "missing declaration/prototype" (or similar) warnings. Provide a [mcve] which compiles without warnings. Running code which produces warnings is useless (for a beginner).

Comment: as i'm not getting any warnings or error i can't say anything about what you guys commented on and the code is working smoothly but for that one part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change your program slightly, it will do what I think you want:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char noreg[11];
    float IPK;
} Mahasiswa;

void showDataArr(Mahasiswa *A, int ukuran) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ukuran; i++) {
        printf("Mhs ke %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("\tNoreg : %s\n", A[i].noreg);
        printf("\tIPK   : %.2f\n", A[i].IPK);
    }
}

void isiDataArr(Mahasiswa *A, int ukuran) {
    int i;
    char temp[20];
    for (i = 0; i < ukuran; i++) {
        printf("Masukan Noreg : ");
        scanf("%s", A[i].noreg);
        getchar();
        printf("Masukan IPK   : ");
        scanf("%f", &A[i].IPK);
        getchar();
    }
}

int n;

int main(void) {
    printf("masukan jumlah data :");
    scanf("%d", &n); //this part
    Mahasiswa PTIK[n];
    isiDataArr(PTIK, n);
    printf("\n");
    showDataArr(PTIK, n);
    //getch();
}
```

**Test**

```
masukan jumlah data :2
Masukan Noreg : 123qwe
Masukan IPK   : 123
Masukan Noreg : 234wer
Masukan IPK   : 234

Mhs ke 1
    Noreg : 123qwe
    IPK   : 123.00
Mhs ke 2
    Noreg : 234wer
    IPK   : 234.00
```

Comment: yes declaring the array later fixed it thank you 
and do you mind if i asked if the difference between main() and int main(void) as it don't really show any difference ?